# sum Array Ascii that accepts an array of strings and returns the sum of all the ascii values of all the characters in all the strings in that array

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii, sum

k I am being asked to Write a function sumArrayAscii that accepts an array of strings and returns the sum of all the ascii values of all the characters in all the strings in that array. Note that this function should use sumAscii from problem.  this is what I have but I cannot get it ti work

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; 
using std::endl; 

int main() 
{ 
int myArrayNumberOfElements(5); 
double myArray[myArrayNumberOfElements] = {1.1, 4.5, 5.7, 7.9, 10}; 
double sum(0); 
for (int i(0); i < myArrayNumberOfElements; i++) 
{ 
sum +=myArray[i]; 
} 

cout << endl << "Sum of all elements: " << sum << endl; 

system("PAUSE"); 
return 0;
```

Comment: where is your `sumArrayAscii` function so far? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want the sum of the ASCII values, or do you want to convert the strings to numbers, and add up those numbers?

Comment: What works? What doesn't? What test inputs and outputs have you generated?

Comment: @KcNorth: [Jesse's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10274612/78845) deals with the **compiler** (not *debuugger*) error you're seeing, but the code you have pasted has nothing to do with your question, it sums an array of `double`s and not ASCII values in a string. You can edit your post to make the code more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you posted calculates the sum of a double array. I see no work with strings or ASCII code for that matter.

These two function worked for me. First function returns the ASCII sum of all characters in a single string. The second one uses the first function in calculating the ASCII sum for a list of strings.

```
int ASCIIsumOfString(string s){
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
    sum += s[i];
}
return sum;}


int ASCIIsumOfStringArray(string *s, int numberOfStrings){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfStrings; i++){
        sum += ASCIIsumOfString(s[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: ok wait you are right it my original does not have the sumASCIIArray in it

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int myArrayNumberOfElements(5);
```

to

```
const int myArrayNumberOfElements(5);
```

The size of the array needs to be constant in C++.